# How can get phrases from a string with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, expression, dom-events

How could I get from the string only the texts `text_add ()` `for_delete ()` `this_edit ()`
and leave them in an array.
I try to occupy a regular expression and filter by the data of the array and it doesn't work for me.
Who can help me?

```
let filter=["_add()","_delete()","_edit()"];

var cadena="text_add()-----for_delete()___ this_edit()  this example is a test hello world";
    
               var myMethod = new RegExp('(\\w*' + filter + '\\w*)', 'gi');
               var matchesMethod = r.match(myMethod);

               if (matchesMethod != null) {
                   arrayMethod.push(matchesMethod.toString().split(","));
               }
```

Comment: If you want to match those exact matches, you could also just check if the string contains whose values instead of using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var cadena="text_add()-----for_delete()___ this_edit()  this example is a test hello world";
var arr = cadena.match(/(\w*\(\))/g);
```

```
\w :  Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
*  :  Match 0 or more characters.
\( :  Matches a "(" character.
\) :  Matches a ")" character.
g  :  global flag
```

here [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAxiAmCmA7EBeARAF3gDwwfTlgAoBKAWgooDMB7MPBAG3i1L3YgwAsBLAZzzxYPDKQidefCDhABbAA7MI-CCE7w+GCF3iNGNCAHc6jWGgDcAKFCRwkFNDhIQAOlkgMULkQD0RADqGAFT+ASQkPgDmJFZQNIh8NMwu+pFEdjFAA)